# Sewer smells/Noxious fumes in house

Tags: septic, sewer-gas

We purchased a house 6 months ago in Western Oregon, a very wet climate.  The old cement septic was cracked on inspection and replaced with a new poly one just prior to our arrival.  The old one was filled with sand and buried.  The new system has a sewer line going to the tank inlet, a line from the tank to the pump chamber, and then a line from the pump to the drainfield.
We noticed sewer smells from day 2.  The smells seemed to be coming from 1 (maybe 2)vents on the roof and throughout the house. No odors or soft spots around tanks or drain field. Did all the usual things:  checked traps (ok), ran water down vent (water flowed, no leaks), toilet seals good.  We had 5 plumbers and the septic installer come out; none of whom could find anything.  The 6th plumber who came out recently installed Odor Hogs on the vent pipes and capped the tee with a test plug at the septic tank inlet.  Sure enough, the odors went away almost immediately.

Now the more serious problem we have is some kind of odorless, noxious fumes filling our house.  It causes my eyes, sinuses, mouth, and throat to burn, tightness in my chest, flushing, and headache.  The weird thing is it really hasn't affected my wife much.  Also, it always seems to get worse in the afternoon or early evening and is bad all night. Called an environmental specialist who said the couldn't help, just use an air scrubber. We already have two HEPA filters running and it doesn't help. I thought it might be an allergic reaction to something but antihistamines and Flonase don't help.

I have been sleeping in the camper and have no idea where to go from here.  Is the old tank still connected to the house or the new system somehow?  Are these fumes unrelated and a red herring?  My wife thinks it's all in my head, but my symptoms tell me to write you instead.

Signed, Nearly Divorced.

Comment: Regrettably, it's hard to help without hard data. There may well be a physical issue (you've heard of Love Canal, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_canal?), but you'd need some measurements. Are there environmental remediation companies in the area? Perhaps a college which has a health department that might help *gratis*?

Comment: Do you have a Carbon Monoxide detector in your house?  Your symptoms might indicate the presence of Carbon Monoxide.  If you don't have one, get everyone out of your house, get a CO detector, or contact your fire department to have them come out and check immediately.

Comment: Different people react differently to different stuff.  I can't be near vomit, but manure, or my hands half way in a cow does not bother me.